# Using the menu bar with user entries: Removing entries

Tags: lists, menu

I would like for the user to be able to add her own entries to the menu bar for the main window, something like this:

- Add a new entry
- -Separator-
- User-added entry 1
- User-added entry 2
- User-added entry 3

And I'm considering different options for how to deal with **removing items from the menu**. So far these are the ideas that I have:

1. A remove menu item can be added for each menu entry (and the sets of two menu entries can be separated with a horizontal line for example)
2. A popup can be shown when clicking on the menu entry (rather than activating it), allowing the option to remove. Then the user would have to use the same popup for activating/triggering that menu entry (making things a little bit slower)
3. Right clicking (I'm not sure if this is supported on all platforms and I'm building a cross-platform application)

Or maybe it's just better to move this into a list inside a window in the application? (Or another option I haven't considered yet?)

Grateful for your help and with kind regards,
Tord

Answer (score 2):

Beware user generated content: they will always add something you haven't thought of.

Based on the fact that this is UGC we're talking about, I would suggest that you need to exercise as much control over the content as you can. To do that, I'd suggest having a control panel dedicated to the menu content where you can signal users that they are exceeding character lengths, exceeding availability, etc - That would also make it easier to manage ordering and deletion of the shortcuts as they could all be handled in a dedicated interface rather than trying to find ways to pack them into the navigation itself.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! It's too complex and unpredictable to handle in the menu bar